# string split operation in R

Tags: r, string, lapply

In my data I have a column of strings. Each string is five characters long. I would like to figure out how to split the string so that I keep the first two characters, the last two and disregard the middle or third character.

I looked at other stackoverflow questions and found the answer listed below as helpful. Initially, the solution below was useful until I saw that in certain cases it didn't work or it worked in the way I wasn't expecting.

This is what I have:

```
statecensusFIPS <- c("01001", "03001", "13144")
newFIPS <- lapply(2:3, function(i){
    if(i==2){
        str_sub(statecensusFIPS, end = i)
    } else {
        str_sub(statecensusFIPS, i)
    }})

StateFIPS <- newFIPS[[1]]
CountyFIPS <- newFIPS[[2]]

# Results
> StateFIPS
[1] "01" "03" "13"
> CountyFIPS
[1] "001" "001" "144"
```

How do I adjust the code so that I have these results instead?

```
StateFIPS
[1] "01" "03" "13"
CountyFIPS
[1] "01" "01" "44"
```

Comment: Why not just `substr(statecensusFIPS,1,2)` and `substr(statecensusFIPS,4,5)`?

Comment: or `str_sub(statecensusFIPS, 1, 2)` and  `str_sub(statecensusFIPS, 4, 5)` if you really want to use `str_sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this (assuming that you want first 2 characters as the statefips and last 2 characters of your strings as county fips and all your strings are of length 5)?

```
statecensusFIPS<-c("01001", "03001", "13144")
newFIPS<-lapply(2:3,function(i) if(i==2) str_sub(statecensusFIPS,end=i) else str_sub(statecensusFIPS,i+1)) 

StateFIPS<-newFIPS[[1]]
CountyFIPS<-newFIPS[[2]]
```

Simpler way could be:

```
statecensusFIPS<-c("01001", "03001", "13144")
stateFIPS<- str_sub(statecensusFIPS,end=2) 
CountyFIPS<- str_sub(statecensusFIPS,4)
```

Comment: Yes, all strings should be of length 5.

Comment: does not this work (almost without changing of your code)

Comment: @ Sandipan It does work. It hasn't worked in my bigger function yet. I did not down vote you though!

Comment: what's the issue in the bigger function you are facing?

Comment: It appears when I apply it to all my data, it deletes leading zero. I will try to solve it and if not post a new question.